# How to assign numerical value to each new grouping in a pandas data frame row?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

If I have a Pandas Data frame like this:

```
     0   1   2   3   4   5
 1  NaN NaN  1  NaN  1   1
 2   1  NaN NaN  1  NaN  1
 3  NaN  1   1  NaN  1   1
 4   1   1   1   1   1   1
 5  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

How do I count each group of ones and assign a value based on the number of groups in each row? Such that I get a data frame like this:

```
     0   1   2   3   4   5
 1  NaN NaN  1  NaN  2   2
 2   1  NaN NaN  2  NaN  3
 3  NaN  1  NaN NaN  2   2
 4   1   1   1   1   1   1
 5  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit hard to finding a simple way

```
s=df.isnull().cumsum(1) # cumsum get the null 
s=s[df.notnull()].apply(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0],1)+1 # then we need assign the groukey 
df=s.mask(s==0)# and mask 0 as NaN 
df
     0    1    2    3    4    5
1  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  2.0  2.0
2  1.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  3.0
3  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  2.0  2.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```